# how to upload image dynamically on server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my application i want to upload the images to server.

I am able to upload images on server but the name of the image mention in front of filename=%@.jpg. remains the same for images

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but i want to save the image on server with the same image name it has......
plz help me out.

following is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)upload:(id)sender
{

    //imageview is a UIImageView 
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 100);


    // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString *urlString = @"http://url.com/upload/uploader.php?";

    // setting up the request object now

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     add some header info now
     we always need a boundary when we post a file
     also we need to set the content type

     You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
     as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
     */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
     */

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    ///self.returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

to

```
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

where filename is a NSString* variable with your desired filename

Answer (score 0):

this line 
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"**Content-Disposition: form-data;** name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

**Content-Type: image/jpeg**

instead of Content-Disposition: form-data

and learn how to use content type