# How to send post data and image file to server Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I upload some text info (a text string) and an image file over the same http post request to server. I got images upload by itself, but can't get text to work with it. Thanks!

Comment: Objective c, This is a similar question, but I need text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone

Comment: Are you using Which web service "REST" "SOAP" or "JSON" which one you will use?

Comment: I'm using php, $_POST['text']; maybe REST at some point

Comment: "Objective c, This is a similar question, but I need text. " I didn't ask what LANGUAGE (it's OBVIOUSLY Objective-C), but which SERVICE. Google docs? Instagram? Dropbox? WHAT?

Comment: here i answered 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474063/how-to-upload-image-dynamically-on-server/15153502#15153502

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this code to upload image and textLabel

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation("yourImage",0.2);     //change Image to NSData

if (imageData != nil)
{
    filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextLabel"];      //set name here
        NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://xxxxxxx/yyyyy.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(returnString);
    NSLog(@"finish");
}
```

In php side use this code

```
$myparam = $_POST['userfile'];     //getting image Here
$mytextLabel= $_POST['filenames']   //getting textLabe Here
echo $myparam;
echo $mytextLabel; 
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);  

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: I can't tell where the text label is being set here, let's say the text is "hello". Where should it go in this code?

Comment: Ok thanks got it, btw I didn't use any of the assetname, or characterset stuff, as I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 4):

Just Add Following Method On Button On Click :

```
-(void) uploadImage
{
    prodNam = txtProdName.text;
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SRT2.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,0.2);     //change Image to NSData

    if (imageData != nil)

    {
        NSString * filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextLabel"];
        NSLog(@"%@", filenames);

        NSString *urlString = @"http://dev9.edisbest.com/upload_image.php";

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"TestEdreamzIpad.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response : %@",returnString);

        if([returnString isEqualToString:@"Success ! The file has been uploaded"])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Image Saved Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }
    NSLog(@"Finish");
    }
}
```

You can put any image at the place of "SRT2.jpg" of your xcode local hierarchy.

All the best...

Comment: Hey can you upload your PHP COde too?
I tried your code but it always say "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"
And no data appear on my server...

Comment: @LaurenzGlück : 


Code For :
upload_image.php

<?php
$target_path  = "iphonetest/";
$target_path = $target_path.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
    echo "0";
}
?>


"iphonetest" is Directory of server placed in root directory.

Use and reply is it worthy to you ?

Comment: @LaurenzGlück : 

<?php
    
    include("include/connect.php");
    include("../wp-config.php");
    /**
     * image upload path for add product
     */
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $target_path  = $wp_upload_dir['path'].'/';
    $target_path = $target_path.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
        echo "1";
        echo $target_path;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0";
        echo $target_path;
    }
    ?>

Answer (score 2):

Simply User [SVHttp Request](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVHTTPRequest) to upload files to server.

send imageFile and other stuffs in parameter :

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [data setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
    [data setObject:@"saveimage" forKey:@"action"];
    [data setObject:userId forKey:@"userid"];
    [data setObject:@"png" forKey:@"type"];
```

And make Request :

```
SVHTTPClient *request = [SVHTTPClient sharedClient];

    [request setBasicAuthWithUsername:nil password:nil];
    [request setSendParametersAsJSON:NO];



    [request POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bylyngo.com/getapi/?action=saveimage&userid=%@&type=png",userId]
       parameters:data
         progress:^(float progress) {

             NSLog(@"Uploading (%.0f%%)", progress*100);

         }];
```

You will get progress even .

:)

Answer (score 1):

My web services is this one and it's working fine!

```
<?php


$fp = fopen("./trace.txt", "w"); //creates a file to trace your data
fwrite($fp,"get \n");
fwrite($fp, print_r($_GET, true));
fwrite($fp,"POST \n");
fwrite($fp, print_r($_POST, true));//displays the POST 
fwrite($fp,"FILES \n");
fwrite($fp,print_r($_FILES,true));//display the FILES 
fclose($fp);


$myparam = $_POST["userfile"];
$mytextLabel = $_POST['filenames'];
echo $myparam;
echo $mytextLabel;


$uploadDir = 'uploads/'; //you must create this directory
$uploadDir = $uploadDir.basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']); //saves the picture inside that folder


$file = basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
//$uploadedFile = $uploadDir.$file;
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tpm_name']);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tpm_name'],$uploadDir)){
echo "the file ".basename($_FILES['myfile']['name'])." has been uploaded" ;
}else{

echo "error";
} 

?>
```