# How to upload the ios audio to server?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mpmediapickercontroller

I have tried to upload the audio files to server. And I have using MPMedia Picker view in list audio, when I am going select the audio I will upload to server(http), How can I do this. Any one can provide any sample tutorial or sample code.

I have tried following code.

```
- (IBAction)openMediaPicker:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES; // this is the default   
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
    [mediaPicker release];
}

- (IBAction)volumeSliderChanged:(id)sender {
    self.musicPlayer.volume = self.volumeSlider.value;
}

#pragma mark MPMediaPickerController delegate methods

- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    // We need to dismiss the picker
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Assign the selected item(s) to the music player and start playback.
    [self.musicPlayer stop];
    [self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
    [self.musicPlayer play];
}

- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {
    // User did not select anything
    // We need to dismiss the picker
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add some more details to get a good answer. Do you have problems on server or client side? What does your server side expect? Do you know how to get handle to audio file? What have you tried?...

Comment: i don't know can you explain?and any sample codes.

Comment: Please have a look, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261928/how-to-send-post-data-and-image-file-to-server-xcode) may help you

Comment: Hi i have done image upload .then i tried audio file uploading but not working.reason audio file path is not correct how get audio path and to parser to server url .

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a MPMediaItem object from some index of the mediaItemCollection.items array:

**MPMediaItem *anItem = (MPMediaItem *)[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: row];**

Then call the -valueForProperty: method:

**NSURL *assetURL = [anItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];**

There are other properties that you can get from the MPMediaItem described here:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Look under "General Media Item Property Keys"

Hope this helps! Tams

Using ASIHTTPRequest to upload an audio file like below,

```
NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:audiourl];
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:SoundPath];
//SoundPath is your audio url path of NSDocumentDirectory.
[request addData:postData withFileName:@"myAudio.caf" andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"company_audio"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

This way you can easily upload audio file on server.

Comment: Hi how to get my audio file name and type.how to parser my url.

Comment: plz tell me your problem is solv or not

Comment: MPMediaItem *anItem = (MPMediaItem *)[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: row]; this used in here - (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
 i'm right .row is showed error

Comment: Hi ,i got this path nsurl *asserturl:  assetURL ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-1116930734541307400