# how to send a NSString as HTTP post request to a python server?

Tags: objective-c, python-2.7

I've followed this [link's tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261928/how-to-send-post-data-and-image-file-to-server-xcode) in my xcode project but i need this to work for a python server, the tutorial is for a PHP server...can anyone help me out to get me a relevant python server for the same .  thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't believe it really matters. The objective-c side will still be the same it will just be the URL that will change and how you handle it on the python side.

Comment: thank u! but as im just a beginner i need help with the python code for the same. it would be great if u could help us with the python code...

Comment: I am only really know the basics of python. So I will leave that for the more experienced users to answer.