# What does "boundary" mean when I post data to php page?

Tags: php, objective-c, post, boundary

I am trying to upload an image to an server.

I do this using an script (in objective-c) and request an php page on the server.
I found on the internet some example code to use (which was very useful).

Link: [How to send post data and image file to server Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261928/how-to-send-post-data-and-image-file-to-server-xcode)

Somewhere in the sample code they are setting "boundaries" before requesting the page. It looks like this:

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"-------------------------- 14737809831466499882746641449" ];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

**Question: What are boundaries and what does it do?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: Googling html boundary gave me the result

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

Comment: So for the server to see the difference between two variables in a GET request we use the "&". And when you use a POST request you have to set boundaries so the server can see the difference? Is this correct? When I use only one variable do I still have to set the boundaries?

Comment: It isn't the difference between POST and GET, it's the difference between multipart form data and other content types (MIME types).